# Facebook dynamic ad retargeting not working from IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Facebook dynamic ad re-targeting is working fine with my Desktop and mobile version of website. But it's not working with my IOS application. As per the Facebook documentation, I had integrated SDK and I'm getting app events and its details correctly in Facebook analytics. But my product ads is not showing in Facebook, if a user is using my IOS application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the problem with campaign, cancelled all existing campaign and started new.